# Multiple PoE devices with single Pi

Tags: networking, poe

Trying to connect a single cable to a Rasberry Pi (PoE) to power it but then I want to add a second device (different IP) and connect it and power it off the Pi is there a way to do that?

We still need a USB connector to power another small device as well

thanks!

Comment: there is always a way to accomplish something ... what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: We are trying to power over PoE both a Pi and a bird dog flex 4k in (with a Poe power breakout). The Pi would power via usb a streamdeck as well.

Comment: Without the technical information I can only guess which is not what you want. Post a simple block diagram of what you are trying to do. With that note the amount of current each node requires. Post links to "Technical Information" on the hardware items. Also let us know how much current per port your POE switch (assumed power source) will supply? We will add all of that up and subtract from the source if the number is negative  it will not work.